# how to integrateYodlee API in Asp.net application

Tags: yodlee

I am currently working on Asp.net application which fetches all the bank details using Yodlee API.Can any one please help me or provide a demo of the integration Process.I have searched many of the google sites but didn't find any satisfying answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just testing then you can refer to http://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_QuickStart

but once you register on developer.yodlee.com then you can access all the relevant document for using the Application.

SampleApplications are also available at http://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Sample_Apps

In case you need more help, you can use the live chat facility available on the developer.yodlee.com.

Comment: Shryeans I have already registered for the yodlee and event gone through the API documntation,but I failed to understand it since am working with the Yodlee for the first time and even I have downloaded the sample code but I only understood the flow if the Sample Apps but how to use it in my app I didn't find that solution